# How to Derive the Key and Initial Vector in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptojs, apple-business-chat

I have a shared key that I need to derive an iv from so I can decipher.

The apple business chat docs state:

Generate the Derived Key and Initial Vector
Run the shared key through the X9.63 Key Derivation Function with SHA256 hash function. This results in a 48-byte payload. Your results should be `rV3qrszd0PMPgeRhNnlOYA==`

Heres what I tried. I used scryptSync and pbkdf2Sync crypto functions with many 'salt' configurations. I'm unsure if these are the correct functions for this job.

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

const keyLength = 48;
// sharedKey is a base64 string
const sharedKey = "2lvSJsBO2keUHRfvPG6C1RMUmGpuDbdgNrZ9YD7RYnvAcfgq/fjeYr1p0hWABeif";
// publicKey is a base64 string
const publicKey = "BDiRKNnPiPUb5oala31nkmCaXMB0iyWy3Q93p6fN7vPxEQSUlFVsInkJzPBBqmW1FUIY1KBA3BQb3W3Qv4akZ8kblqbmvupE/EJzPKbROZFBNvxpvVOHHgO2qadmHAjHSg=="

const key1 = crypto.scryptSync(sharedKey, 'salt', keyLength);
console.log(key2.toString('base64'));

const key2 = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(sharedKey, 'salt', 10000, keyLength, 'sha256');
console.log(key2.toString('base64'));

// results should be:
// mAzkYatDlz4SzrCyM23NhgL/+mE3eGgfUz9h1CFPhZM=
// iv: rV3qrszd0PMPgeRhNnlOYA==
```

Below is the Apple sample code for Deriving the Key and Initial Vector with a X9.63 Key Derivation Function.

```py
    def ITOSP(self, longint, length):
        """ITOSP, short for Integer-to-Octet-String Primitive, converts a non-negative integer
        to an octet string of a specified length. This particular function is defined in the
        PKCS #1 v2.1: RSA Cryptography Standard (June 14, 2002)
        https://www.cryptrec.go.jp/cryptrec_03_spec_cypherlist_files/PDF/pkcs-1v2-12.pdf"""

        hex_string = "%X" % longint
        assert len(hex_string) <= 2 * length, "ITOSP function: Insufficient length for encoding"
        return binascii.a2b_hex(hex_string.zfill(2 * length))

    def KDFX963(self, inbyte_x, shared_data, key_length, hashfunct=sha256, hash_len=32):
        """KDFX963 is a key derivation function (KDF) that takes as input byte sequence inbyte_x
        and additional shared data shared_data and outputs a byte sequence key of length
        key_length. This function is defined in ANSI-X9.63-KDF, and this particular flavor of
        KDF is known as X9.63. You can read more about it from:
        http://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf"""

        assert key_length >= 0, "KDFX963 function: key_length should be positive integer"
        k = key_length / float(hash_len)
        k = int(ceil(k))

        acc_str = ""
        for i in range(1, k+1):
            h = hashfunct()
            h.update(inbyte_x)
            h.update(self.ITOSP(i, 4))
            h.update(shared_data)
            acc_str = acc_str + h.hexdigest()

        return acc_str[:key_length * 2]
```

Comment: To be clear: your intent is to write new Javascript code that does something similar to the Python example code?

Comment: I need to derive the iv from the sharedKey with Node.js. The python code is what Apple gave to me as an example. I'm definitely not trying to port all of that code over. @KarlKnechtel

Comment: Okay, but the sample code, nor anything like it, is not intended to be part of the project? It's just for reference here?

Comment: Correct! The python code is just for reference. My project uses Node.js as stated in the title: How to Derive the Key and Initial Vector in Node.js.

Comment: Aha. Then it shouldn't be tagged as `python` and I removed that.

Comment: You need a NodeJS implementation of the X9.63 KDF, preferably from a library, otherwise, if you can't find one, make your own. The algorithm is described e.g. in [SEC1, section 3.6.1](http://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsubsection.3.6.1). scrypt and PBKDF2 are KDFs, but different, and won't help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

X9.63 KDF is a key derivation function, described e.g. [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8418#section-2.1) and [here](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsubsection.3.6.1). scrypt and PBKDF2 are also KDFs, but different ones, so of course the expected result cannot be reproduced with them.

So you need a NodeJS library that supports X.963 KDF. If you can't find one, you could also implement your own.

X9.63 KDF expects a shared secret and a shared info and determines a *keysize* large key as follows:

- Create a 4 byte counter c<sub>i</sub> which is incremented starting with 0x0000001.
- Concatenate the data conc<sub>i</sub> = shared secret | c<sub>i</sub> | shared info
- Hash the result hash<sub>i</sub> = hash(conc<sub>i</sub>)
- Concatenate the hashes hash<sub>1</sub> | hash<sub>2</sub> | ... until an output of length *keysize* has been generated.

More formally, including various checks, the algorithm is described in the links above. The Python code posted later in the question also implements this logic.

One possible NodeJS implementation (omitting the checks from the specification) is:

```js
var crypto = require('crypto');

var digest = 'sha256';
var digestLen = 32;

function X963KDF(sharedSecret, sharedInfo, keySize){
  var maxCount = Math.ceil(keySize/digestLen);
  var result = Buffer.allocUnsafe(0);
  for (var count = 1; count < maxCount + 1; count++){
      var counter = Buffer.allocUnsafe(4);
      counter.writeUInt32BE(count, 0);
      var current = Buffer.concat([sharedSecret, counter, sharedInfo]);
      var hash = crypto.createHash(digest).update(current).digest();
      result = Buffer.concat([result, hash]);
  }
  
  return result.slice(0, keySize);
}
```

---

Test:

In the question the shared secret is posted, but not the shared info. An internet search reveals that the posted problem is described e.g. [here](https://www.examplefiles.net/cs/1349231), so that the shared info can also be determined (nevertheless it would be better if you add this information to your question):

```js
var sharedSecret = Buffer.from('2lvSJsBO2keUHRfvPG6C1RMUmGpuDbdgNrZ9YD7RYnvAcfgq/fjeYr1p0hWABeif', 'base64')
var sharedInfo = Buffer.from('04389128d9cf88f51be686a56b7d6792609a5cc0748b25b2dd0f77a7a7cdeef3f111049494556c227909ccf041aa65b5154218d4a040dc141bdd6dd0bf86a467c91b96a6e6beea44fc42733ca6d139914136fc69bd53871e03b6a9a7661c08c74a', 'hex');

var keyiv = X963KDF(sharedSecret, sharedInfo, 48);
var key = keyiv.slice(0,32).toString('base64');
var iv = keyiv.slice(32, 48).toString('base64');
console.log("Key: ", key); // Key:  mAzkYatDlz4SzrCyM23NhgL/+mE3eGgfUz9h1CFPhZM=
console.log("IV: ", iv); // IV:  rV3qrszd0PMPgeRhNnlOYA==
```

The generated key and IV are equal to the expected values.

Comment: Indeed you are correct. The shared info should be the public key. I will update this post.